# KeyPairValue Linq how to set value

Tags: linq, dictionary

How can I set a value of Dictionary?

```
public class Holding
{
    public Dictionary<int, double> QuantityPricePair { get; set; }

    public Holding()
    {
        QuantityPricePair = new Dictionary<int, double>();
    }
}
```

Linq querying to find an object

```
KeyValuePair<int, double> query = holding.QuantityPricePair.Where(h => h.Value == 7).SingleOrDefault();
if (query.Key != 0)
{
    query.Value = 3;
}
```

I cannot compile the code, claiming that KeyValuePair has no setter

Comment: You can only return a new dictionary.

Comment: `KeyValuePair` is immutable - you can't change it.  All you can do is create a _new_ one, or use the dictionary's indexer to update the value for a given key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`KeyValuePair<K,V>` is an immutable object that refers to one key/value pair in the dictionary. You can't change any part of the `KeyvaluePair` object. But if you want to change the value in the dictionary for that key, that's easy to do -- you've got the dictionary right there:

```
if (query != null && query.Key != 0)
{
    holding.QuantityPricePair[query.Value] = 3;
}
```

`SingleOrDefault()` can return `null`, so don't neglect to take that into account.

If the goal isn't to change the dictionary's own value there, if instead you just want to alter the `KeyValuePair` before doing something else with it, you can easily create a new `KeyValuePair` instead, and nobody will ever know the difference:

```
if (query != null && query.Key != 0)
{
    query = new KeyValuePair<int, double>(query.Key, 3);
}
```

Again, note that the second version can't possibly alter the value stored in the dictionary.

Comment: I think you mean `holding.QuantityPricePair[query.Key] = 3`